# Whenever I put my cursor over a subcategory it closed the drop down menu and the subcategory link

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a drop down menu for a site. The drop down menu is different from many other drop down menus, but everytime I put my cursor over a subcategory, it closed the Drop down menu, and the subcategory. Please try to fix it. Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

    a:link {
    color: black;
    }


    a:visited {
    color: black;
}


a:hover {
    color: lightBlack;
}


a:active {
     color: gray;
}

a {
     text-decoration: none;

}



a.rel {
    position: relative;


    }

.sa {
    color:white;

    }
.sd {
border-right-style:visible;border-right-width:1px; border-bottom- style:visible                               
border-bottom-color:black; border-bottom-width: 5px;
background-color: #040404;
border-bottom:#040404;
border-right: solid 2px;
border-right-color:gray;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">

a:link {
    color: black;
}


a:visited {
    color: black;
}


a:hover {
    color: lightBlack;
}


a:active {
    color: gray;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;

}



rel {
    position: relative;


}

.sa {
    color:white;

    }
.sd {
    border-right-style:visible;border-right-width:1px; border-bottom-style:        visible; 
    border-bottom-color:black; border-bottom-width: 5px;
    background-color: #040404;
    border-bottom:#040404;
    border-right: solid 2px;
    border-right-color:gray;
    }
</style>
<font size="5">
<img src = "chan-art2.png" cellspacing="0" border="0"/><br/>
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
        color: white;
}


a:visited {
        color: white;
}


a:hover {
        color: #AEAEAE;
        transition: color 0.3s;
}
a:active {
    color: white;
}

#text1 a:hover {
    font-size:20px;
    color: black;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition: font-size .5s,color .5s;


    }
    span#menuspan:hover {
        padding-bottom: 300px;
        padding-right: 100px;
        border-bottom-style:visible;
        border-bottom-color: gray;
        border-bottom: block 2px;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition: padding-bottom .6s, padding-right .5s;


}



</style>
<div>
<span class="sd"><a cellspacing="0"           href="#no_link_so_far_put_one_here">About</a></span><span onmouseout="iv()"  onmouseover="univ()" cellspacing="0" id="menuspan" class="sd"><a
href="index.html">Home</a><br/></span><br/>
<div style="padding-left: 70px;">
<a id="newr" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; margin-top:    none;border:none;" href="#" >New Releases</a>
</div>
</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I know the problem. The subcategory is not part of the drop down menu, so whenever I hover over it, it will register that I am not hovering over the menu, which it then closes it. I got another method going, fortunately, so I dont need much help anymore.